# Android Development: Change ImageView Source in A ListView

Tags: android, listview, runtime, imageview

I'm struggling to understand how I'd go about changing an ImageView's src at runtime in a ListActivity.

In a function I have this line which is where the custom file row is set for the ListView:

```
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.listtext, this.directoryEntries));
```

In listrow.xml, I have an ImageView which I would like to set the src as a folder image or a file image (for my file browser).

I don't set the content view to listrow.xml so I can't simple go:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.listicon); 
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.foldericon);
```

So how can I do it?
Sorry if I'm not making much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `ArrayAdapter`, you will need to make a subclass, override `getView()`, and replace your image there. [Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that describes the techinques.